# AngularJS: Updating ngModel property when select options change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It is easy to use Angular data binding to force a JavaScript property to change when a user changes the item selected in a menu.  However, I cannot figure out how to force a data bound property to change when the model used to generate a menu changes.

This fiddle demonstrates the behavior:  http://jsfiddle.net/2pHGX/.  Changing the model by clicking changeOptions causes the select options to change correctly.  But the data bound property does not change immediately, it only changes when the user selects a different menu option.

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="bodyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selection" ng-options="option for option in options">
    </select>
    <button ng-click="changeOptions()">changeOptions</button>
    <br>
    selection: {{selection}}
</body>

function bodyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.options = [10, 20, 30];
    $scope.changeOptions = function() {
        $scope.options = [11, 22, 33];
    };
}
```

I want the data bound property to update when the selected option changes for any reason, either because the user picked a different option or because the model, and therefore options, changed.  I can make this work with `$watch`, but I cannot understand why data binding alone is not sufficient.  What is the best way to accomplish this with Angular?  Am I misunderstanding something fundamental about data binding?

Comment: you want to keep the same index?

Comment: My naive expectation is that, when the options for a data bound select change, the pre-change value will continue to be selected if it appears anywhere in the new options regardless of index, and an empty option will be selected otherwise

Comment: I think I see what you mean.  You are expecting `{{selection}}` to change to `<emptystring>` when the `changeOptions()` is fired. I think I would expect the same.  Interesting...

Comment: Defining the ng-model creates a scope variable called "selection". When you change the ng-options, you don't trigger the change that would update "selection". It's a separate and unrelated variable at this point. I like davin's answer below, because it appropriately treats DOM events and the data as entirely independent entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the exact behaviour that you want, but you can always watch options and, therefore, on change take an action ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davintryon/yYxP8/)):

```
function bodyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selection = 0;
    $scope.options = [ 10, 20, 30];
    $scope.changeOptions = function() {
        $scope.options = [11, 22, 33];
    };

    $scope.$watch('options', function() {
        $scope.selection = 0;
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the OP is wanting to know WHY the change isn't automatic.  It would seem that the model should change with the change in options, since they are seemingly bound together.

Comment: @rGil How are they bound together?  The selection action of the drop down binds back the selected value.  Changing the options only changed what the list is bound to.

Comment: The behavior I expected is for the data bound property to always accurately reflect the currently selected option. That does not happen in some circumstances,  for example when the options are changed due to model change. Does that clarify my question?

Comment: @Chris By changing the options, you are not changing the model value (of `selection`).

Comment: @Chris Just to clarify, when you declare the attribute `ng-model="selection"`, under the hood, angular adds a new scope field named `selection`.  So, there is no implicit bound connection.  On selection of the list, the `selection` field is updated.

Comment: @Davin Do you know of Angular documentation that goes into detail about data binding internals?  Your answer is the clearest explanation I have seen yet.  As rGil suggests, I want to understand the subtleties behind this behavior

Answer (score 5):

If you directly bind ng-model to a scope variable as below, the scope variable somehow will not be updated.

```
<select ng-model="selection" ng-options="option for option in options">
```

Instead, define a view model in your scope and bind ng-model to a field of view model the view model field will be updated.

```
<select ng-model="viewmodel.selection" ng-options="option for option in options">
```

In your controller, you should do this:

```
app.controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope'
    function($scope)
    {
        $scope.viewmodel = {};
    });
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks dude, any idea what is going on here? Normally I can bind to models directly in the scope

Comment: @HaveAGuess Do not know the reason yet... In many situations, I have to put variables inside a view model to have them updated.

Comment: Thanks. Really weird as I have a fairly large app running without a view model up until now :(